# Is there any reason not to use HttpOnly for all cookies?

Tags: php, session, cookies, session-cookies

Are there any downsides to enabling HttpOnly for all cookies?

If not, why isn't it HttpOnly by default in php.ini?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It stops you accessing the cookies with JavaScript, which is something that you might want to do.

Additionally, switching it on by default would break backwards compatibility with sites written before the option existed.

Comment: But isn't allowing cookies to be accessed by JavaScript a big security flaw? Why would anyone allow it?

Comment: It isn't a security flaw per se; it just exposes you to increased consequences if you have an XSS vulnerability in some other part of the code. A site might want to manipulate its own cookies with JavaScript.

Answer (score 1):

I suspect because [not all browsers support HttpOnly](http://www.browserscope.org/?category=security&v=top).  Support of course [changes over time](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/HttpOnly#Browsers_Supporting_HttpOnly), and I can't imagine this reason standing forever.

**Update**
I checked the commit history of `session.c` and note that the first and only call to setting the default value was done in the original commit back in 2005.  Way back then, a lot of (most?) browsers did not support HttpOnly.

Further, [the docs on httponly say](http://www.php.net/manual/en/session.configuration.php#ini.session.cookie-httponly):

> This setting can effectively help to reduce identity theft through XSS 
>   attacks (**although it is not supported by all browsers**).

Emphasis mine.  Based on this, it seems to me the reason it is not on by default has to do with browser support and no one has opened up a ticket to make it default to on.

@Quentin is right, but with the emphasis placed on security in the ZCE, I would expect a 'default closed' policy would be better, though that would break BC.  Something to be argued in the feature request.